# Pickle loading error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle

Here is my code

```
  #my process class----------
  class Process(object):

      def PrintName(self, name):
         print('Your name is : ', name)
    #pickling-------------
    import pickle
    model = Process()
    filename = 'Process.pkl'
    pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

    #loading the pickle-------------

    model = pickle.load(open('Process.pkl', 'rb'))
```

while i run above code on jupyter notebook,i got an error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Process',
confused which line causes the error

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you importing pickle twice?

Comment: Also: is the indentation just like in your project?

Comment: @teekeks ,i have edited the question.the indentation is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, Indentation is important.
Everything after your function was still part of the class Process due to a error in your indentation.

you can read more about indentation and coding styles in general for python [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?)

I formated your code according to PEP8 for you and it should work now:

```
import pickle


# my process class----------
class Process(object):

    def PrintName(self, name):
        print('Your name is : ', name)


# pickling-------------
model = Process()
filename = 'Process.pkl'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

# loading the pickle-------------

model = pickle.load(open('Process.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Comment: appreciate for your time,indeed it helped me

Comment: if this solved your problem, please accept the answer by hitting that checkmark next to my answer